# React Callback Unmount Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've a problem with an HTML node.
Inside a NavBar I've a dropdown from materializecss.

To get the element I used a createCallback hook, because I need to grab the node after the DOM updated.

(useEffect did not worked, because sometimes the node is null)

```
  const nodeRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      M.Dropdown.init(node);
    }
  }, []);
```

This will initialize the element and then i refer to this into the node:

```
<div
  ...
  ref={nodeRef}
  data-target="dropdown1"
>
```

Problem is:

I've a visibility condition on the component with that NODE inside of him, like this one:

```
{visible && <Component />}
```

When I change the VISIBLE value(with some action dispatched elsewhere, I'm using the context API), React will give me an error on the UnorderedList ... and then:

```
DOMException: "Node was not found"
```

Probably he's trying to update the state, but the node is not there anymore and It's memoized?

How can I unmount the NODE and then hide the entire component?

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: glad you got it working even though it sounded a bit hacky. I deleted the answer as it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. `useCallback` doesn't send any parameters to the argument function and it returns a function, not the result of the function.

Comment: Strange enough It works... and the NODE is instantiated... so what do you suggest?

Comment: If "it works", I don't know what your question is, @FabioRusso.

Comment: @FabioRusso Obviously your code doesn't work, or you wouldn't be asking the question. I've tried to suggest one of the avenues for exploring, because your code is using `useCallback` in an incorrect manner.

Comment: @lonesomeday that function is checking if the node has been created in the dom just by executing the M.init() from materializecss

Comment: @FabioRusso Well, I'm not sure how you're attempting to do that, but passing the return value of `useCallback` to `ref` is not the way to do.

Comment: @lonesomeday well ok... so what’s the right way? Te “value” inside my callbackRef contains the DOM node with ref on It. So I thought It was working.